# How can I use the YouTube SUP API to retrieve recent uploads of some predefined users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, youtube-api

I wish to be able to check for the latest videos (in near realtime or at most a couple of minutes out) for a set of users (up to 200 or so) in a single call to the YouTube API and then store the IDs of uploaded videos in my own database. The only solution I believe there is for this is the YouTube SUP API but I'm not entirely clear on how it works and was wondering if someone could please explain it. I have read the entire API documentation on it but am still not completely clear.

I was assuming that one can call the SUP URL (`http://gdata.youtube.com/sup`) and check if the user hash has had any activity recently and if they have, then do something with that. My issue is I don't understand how you  interpret the activity from `["b305e88","afd4"]` in the SUP feed and is there any way to specify a subset of users or must you search through the entire feed? It seems to take a fair few seconds to load the SUP feed.

On the [SUP API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_sup#Retrieving_SUP_Feed) page it also states that you can visit a URL such as `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/bbc/events?v=2` to obtain the hash key for a user's feed, but as you can see if you try to visit it, the link appears to be broken. How else could I obtain the hash?

I'm currently wanting to do this in a Rails project while using the [youtube_it](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) gem but I don't believe this has support for it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Edit**

My mistake. The developer key is required to obtain the events of a user such as `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/bbc/events?v=2&key=YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY`

Still no progress with the SUP method although I'm potentially considering using a channel and just automatically subscribing to each user. Every minute I will then poll for the list of new videos by the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using PubSubHubbub: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/10/pubsubhubbub-for-youtube-activities.html

A handler in your web application will automatically receive a POST whenever one of the feeds you're watching is updated, and the content of the POST will be the updated feed itself, saving you the trouble of having to fetch it.

There isn't much documentation specific to using PuSH and the YouTube API beyond that blog post, but the general PuSH docs all apply: https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/

Failing that, SUP should still work, so we could try to debug that further if you'd rather use that.

Comment: Currently I have managed to solve this by periodically requesting (every 10 seconds) the new subscription videos of an account I've created specifically for the service but I'll definitely look into PubSubHubbub down the line. Thanks!